# Check the type of file clicked in a listbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, listbox

How can I check the file type of an object in my listbox?

I'm returning a list of strings from an online server and simply wanting to have an event that gets fired when I click on an item that has a .folder file type at the end.

I've tried looking but can't find anything.

Can someone please provide a link or sample code so I can achieve what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Do all items in the list box have some extension (like .folder)?

Comment: Yes. Mostly image file types though like .jpg and .png but its specifically the .folder type I'm after.

Comment: So, you pull down this list of strings, display it to the user, they click on one that has a .folder extension, and an event is fired?

Comment: @Sean please review the differnt answers and comment on the ones that dont exactly solved what you need or even better mark one of them as correc answer

Comment: @Mauricio just did mate. No need for a comment like that man. I know how this site works.

Comment: @Sean I have seen many questions that have many answers and the OP never gave credit, that is why I do it

Comment: @Sean Please see my upadated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include the FileInfo assembly and use FileInfo.Extension.

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
string fileName = finfo.Extension
```

Comment: you are assuming that filename is a full file path, which is never mentioned

Comment: You shouldn't need a full file path for .Extension to work. FileInfo("blahblah.fakeext") will return ".fakeext" when .Extension is called. Although, to be fair, I believe it's really just calling lastindexof('.') :)

Comment: Ooh, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695502/does-fileinfo-extension-return-the-last-pattern-or-something-else .Extension searches from the end of the string backwards to the first period.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string item ;

    item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if(item.EndsWith(".folder"))
    {
        //it's a .folder, raise the event or react as needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you;

```
   private void listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
     string item=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
     int index=item.LastIndexOf('.');
     if(index>=0)//It's a valid file
      {
       string extension=item.Substring(index+1,item.Length-index-1);
       if(extension=="folder")
       {
        MessageBox.Show("Yes it's a .folder");
       }
      }
     else if(index==-1)//Not a valid file
      {
        MessageBox.Show("The selected file is invalid.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: why the need to use LastIndexOf and Substring and not used EndsWith ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia If the item is `folder.folder` just as you said then why would it not work if it works for `somefolder.folder`,`music.folder`.I mean I am not checking anywhere what _item_ contains before `last .`,so there would be no issues.

Comment: Aviral I am not saying what happens if its "folder.folder" I am asking if its just "folder" with no dot "."

Comment: @MauricioGracia Thanks for pointing it,I forgot to include something if this happens.I will update it.

Comment: the logic is too complex considered the complexity of the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the folder extension event

```
private void listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
string file=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
 if(ext ==".folder")
 {
    //raise event
 }
}
```